# How to input time into a structure?

Tags: c, malloc, scanf, typedef

I'm writing a code that get a line from a user, and that line's format is like

`2018/Jan/22`

Yes it's year/month/day:hour:minute:second.
And I want the output of this code like

`2018-01-22`

month is changed to number.

and the time is stored to typedef.

```
typedef struct{
int year, month, day;
}Date;

Date Time[];

...

//in main() a user enters a number, and then memory allocated.
Date* p=(Date*)malloc(sizeof(Date)*number);

...
```

In this situation, I thought it would be okay to use scanf() to get entered the line user enters.
So I wrote

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
scanf("%d/%d/%d",p->year, p->month, p->day);
...
}
```

But it doesn't work. Why? I can't catch it.

Comment: What does this have to do with sorting? Fix the title to be relevant and agree with the *actual* issue/ask.

Comment: Also, check out what “%d” *means* as a format specifier, and why this is definitely not appropriate for the input (nor is directly reading into the int field). scanf *won’t* convert “Jan” to 1 automatically.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not an adequate description of a problem. In the future, do better. If you're getting compiler warnings, mention these. If you're getting a compiler error, provide it. If you're program is crashing, provide the exit status. If a function doesn't behave as expected, provide any error it might provide (e.g. `scanf` returns a significant value in this regard). etc

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` can't change variables it doesn't know about. As such, `scanf` requires pointers to the variables to change. You want:

```c
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &(p->year), &(p->month), &(p->day));
```

(The parens aren't necessary.)

ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings and heed them. (I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc or clang.)

Note that `Jan` is not a number, so `2018/Jan/22` would not be a valid input. Many more changes are needed to support `2018/Jan/22`.